# Display content if woocommerce coupon is valid or invalid or not entered

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I am creating a shortcode that will display the coupon code field. I will be placing this short-code on home page I would like to conditionally display some text in the short-code once the coupon is applied.

If the coupon is applied successfully, I would like to display a success message.

If no coupon is applied, I would like to display the coupon code field.

If the coupon entered within the field is invalid, I would like to return "Coupon invalid" with the coupon field.

So far this is what I have to display coupon field:

```
    public static function coupon_field( $atts, $content = null ) {

    $output = '';
    $output.='<form class="checkout_coupon" method="post">
    <p class="form-row form-row-first">
        <input type="text" name="coupon_code" class="input-text" placeholder="Discount code" id="coupon_code" value="" />
    </p>
    <p class="form-row form-row-last">
        <input type="submit" class="button" name="apply_coupon" value="Apply Discount" />
    </p>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    </form>';
        return $output;
    }
```

I am looking for something that would function similar to this:

```
    public static function coupon_field( $atts, $content = null ) {

    $output = '';
        if(!isset($coupon_code)){

    $output.='<form class="checkout_coupon" method="post">
    <p class="form-row form-row-first">
        <input type="text" name="coupon_code" class="input-text" placeholder="Discount code" id="coupon_code" value="" />
    </p>
    <p class="form-row form-row-last">
        <input type="submit" class="button" name="apply_coupon" value="Apply Discount" />
    </p>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    </form>'; }

        elseif($coupon_code != get_post($coupon->id)){

         $output.='<p>coupon invalid </p>

         <form class="checkout_coupon" method="post">
    <p class="form-row form-row-first">
        <input type="text" name="coupon_code" class="input-text" placeholder="Discount code" id="coupon_code" value="" />
    </p>
    <p class="form-row form-row-last">
        <input type="submit" class="button" name="apply_coupon" value="Apply Discount" />
    </p>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    </form>'; }


        else{
            $output = '<p>coupon applied</p>';
        }

        }
        return $output;
```

Any and all help would be much appreciated.

Comment: what is the problem?